# replacing of "draw together" in the following context

Tags: word-choice

I need something clearer than "draw together" in the following sentence because it's not clear to the reader what I mean. I mean that if we attach two lines (of two directions) to each other, they create two dimensional.

> "If we **draw together** two lines of two different directions, these
>   two lines are called “two dimensional” since they are two axes"

Comment: Do you mean draw at the same time?  If so "simultaneously draw" would be a good choice.

Comment: I mean the separate time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we draw two **connected** lines (in two different directions), these two lines *would be* called “two dimensional” since *there* are two axes."